# Broke my SharePoint site by modifying master page, help!

Tags: javascript

I was attempting to add Javascript that would remove the "recently viewed" list of the SharePoint page.  I ended up removing the code, and upon saving the page and navigating to the SharePoint site, I was greeted by nothing except for a white screen.  None of the pages of the SharePoint site will load.  Central Administration loads just fine.

I tried using the "reset to site definition" functionality but the button is disabled.  Also, the "v4.master" master page will not work either.

How do I revert/restore back to my default masterpage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the SharePoint version ?

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

1. Review the error log and it will have exceptions related to failed loading of controls or reference files. so review those first to understand the extent of the problem.
2. go to the similar site that was created with same site template and open that master page in designer. Copy the source code and replace the broken master page. it should fix the issues very easily.
3. make sure to publish the master page or check-in after fixing the issues - just to make sure that the changes will get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Version History of masterpage and restore the last known good save.